# add HBase Timestamp using Phoenix-Spark API

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

How do I add an HBase Timestamp using Phoenix-Spark similiar to HBase API:

```
Put(rowkey, timestamp.getMillis)
```

This is my code:

```
val rdd = processedRdd.map(r => Row.fromSeq(r))
val dataframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
dataframe.save("org.apache.phoenix.spark", SaveMode.Overwrite,
    Map("table" -> HTABLE, "zkUrl" -> zkQuorum))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently not supported in Phoenix. Maybe, you need to use HBase api instead of Phoenix.

Comment: Is it supported in HBase 1.1.2 & Phoenix 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
dataframe.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode("overwrite").option("table", "HTable").option("zkUrl", "xxxx:0000").save()
```